# Sharepoint 2010 Development Environment Set-up

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need advise on what can be best way to setup/configure SHAREPOINT 2010 Environment for 6-members teams (with 3-working at onsite and 2-working at offshore)

Currently I only had two team members but team is now increasing. What we have is DEVELOPMENT SERVER - with Visual Studio and SharePoint Server installed. Developers remote VNC to the box and do their development.

But with number of developers are increasing what should be ideal, so that team can communicate from offshore/onshore

Is this Ideal (installed on each developer laptop)
Visual Studio 2010 
and 
SharePoint Server (Installed on Windows Server 2008) and developers will use this rather than installing SharePoint locally (enterprise edition is very expensive)

Comment: You might get help from http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start to developing with SharePoint 2010 in the team one and half years ago. We try different environment structures for developing, but had many conflicts. Today everyone work in his own environment (HV) with SP enterprise edition, just sharing the code via Team System. The problem is in this set-up the content, everybody has his special content, but if it is critical for you, make backup in every environment.
So we have one SQL server, and for every developer a server with SP and VS.

---

By the way I think you don't need to purchase SharePoint Server for development environment. If I'm right it is free. You need purchase OS, Sql, VS, but not the SP. Please check with your Microsoft seller.

Comment: Correct, installing SP 2010 does not require a license, for dev purposes. You just need appropriate licenses for your web environment.

It's also possible to install SP on Windows 7, for dev purposes, so you don't need a bunch of Windows Server licenses.